# Which version IList[i].Method() call?

Tags: c#, list, mutable

Which version `IList<T>[i].Method()` call for indexer? The set version or get version? I have a `List<MutableStruct> list`. I call a mutable method by `list[0].MutableMethod()` and find `list[0]` is not changed. I think it calls get version and an implicit copy makes the unexpected. Please confirm. Thanks.

Comment: Mutable structs are evil and you're seeing why first hand.

Comment: The only way to mutate a struct via indexer is using an **array** indexer. All other are returning a copy due to `get` semantics.

Answer (score 4):

That's because when a struct is passed you get a copy of the entire struct vs reference types where the copy is of the reference.  This means that once you get the struct out of the list you have a copy and the method is called on that copy and not on the one in the list.  For this to work you'd have to assign the value in the list to a variable, then mutate it, then assign it back.  That's why mutable structs are considered a bad idea

Example

```
public struct MutableStruct
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public void MutableMethod()
    {
        Value = 5;
    }
}
```

With this code

```
var list = new List<MutableStruct>();
list.Add(new MutableStruct());

Console.WriteLine(list[0].Value);
list[0].MutableMethod();
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Value);
var x = list[0];
x.MutableMethod();
list[0] = x;
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Value);
```

Outputs

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 5